# hide header on scroll but when you reach the bottom and scroll up the header shows

Tags: javascript, html

I wasnt entirely sure how to ask this question so I'm not sure if this question already exists..

I have a header that hides after you scroll down like so..

```js
 let prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
 window.onscroll = function() {
    let currentScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
      if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
        const header = document.getElementById('app-program-header');
        header.style.top = '0';
    } else {
        const header = document.getElementById('app-program-header');
        header.style.top = '-50px';
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollpos;
};
```

```html
<div style="height: 50px; width: 100%; background-color: black; position: absolute;" id="app-program-header">
</div>
<div style="height: 150vh; background: pink; width: 100%;" class="body">
</div>
```

but what I want to happen is if you reach the bottom of the page and then scroll up I want the header to come back in.. Im not entirely sure how I would be able to do something like this

**EDIT**

due to how mobiles scroll, I need to be able to change the scroll up offset by 10, 20px so the header doesnt come back in immediately as you scroll up

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added `var direction` to judge the scroll up/down,

and let `<div id="app-program-header">` is `position=fixed`.

then use `style.display` to determinate display header or not instead of `style.top`.

```js
var prevScrollpos = 0;
var maxScrollpos = 0;
window.onscroll = function() {
  let currentScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
  let direction = currentScrollpos - prevScrollpos;
  let header = document.getElementById('app-program-header');
  if(direction<0 && (maxScrollpos - currentScrollpos) > 50){ //if minus, scroll up
    header.style.top = '5px';
    header.style.display = 'block';
  }
  else{
    maxScrollpos = currentScrollpos > maxScrollpos ? currentScrollpos : maxScrollpos
    if (prevScrollpos < 50) {
        header.style.display = 'block';
        maxScrollpos = 0;
    } else {
        header.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollpos;
};
```

```html
<div id="app-program-header" style="top:5px;height:20px;display:block;background-color:green;position:fixed;">
header
</div>
<div style="height:800px;margin-top:40px;">
body
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @Sphinx, is there a way I can offset when the header shows up on the scroll up?? I tried to change `direction < -10 and < 10` but that didnt work Im not entirely sure how I could do that. Instead of being revealed immediately I would like it if after 10 or 20px the header is then revealed

Comment: added `var maxScrollpos ` to implement the effect you mentioned.